# C++ Port in VS: new project crashes (same files & settings)

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, console-application, windows

I am trying to move the code from a preliminary project to a new project (both made under Visual Studio 2012).

The original one has been made as a **console application** and I want the new to be a **Windows application**. I created an empty project and moved the files/set the library paths.

It is a simple OpenGL program with shaders.

### EDIT:

It happens that even when I switch back to creating a Console application **with the same .vcproj properties**, I have a fatal error on Release and Debug.
You can find them below.

Why does my program crash? All the library paths are set just fine because it's the same settings used for **a previous project with the same files that DID work** (in a different solution).

### Errors

Release crash location (outside a #ifdef _DEBUG in the *dbghook.c*
 file)

```
 int _debugger_hook_dummy;

 __declspec(noinline)
 void __cdecl _CRT_DEBUGGER_HOOK(int _Reserved)
 {
     /* assign 0 to _debugger_hook_dummy so that the function is not folded in retail */
     (_Reserved);
     _debugger_hook_dummy = 0;
 }
```

Debug crash location (*fread.c*) - a pop-up error window appears
 (*Debug assertion failed*):

```
  _VALIDATE_RETURN((stream != NULL), EINVAL, 0);
```

Comment: Why not just create a new Windows application with the wizard and put in your files? Or create one console application and one windows application and compare what the differences in the vcproj are?

Comment: This sounds more like an library compatibility issue. Make sure that the GLUT build you're using is compatible with your version of VC++ (compiler, linker and runtime libraries).

Comment: I have made a comparison (with Araxis) so that EVERY SINGLE parameter in the .vcproj files match, between 2 Console applications. Still can't make the new project run...

Answer (score 0):

After cutting my source file in parts, I managed to debug this. The problem was not the port (sorry).

I had minor issues dealing with the location of the executable: Visual Studio puts them by default in SolutionDir/DebugorRelease while I was looking for them in ProjectDir/DebugorRelease.

But the main problem came from a change of function.
There is a side file I use to load textures, which is pretty old and uses *fopen* to open files.

Following the warnings I got, I changed **all the fopen occurrences to fopen_s**, with all necessary modifications. That's the precise line where the program crashed.

I put back the **fopen version**, checked the file locations, and it went back to executing (not in Visual Studio but through command line only, like the original project). That's for the Console Application.

To make it a Windows Application, the following line does the job, and this time, though command-line-only, it works for real.

```
#pragma comment( linker, "/subsystem:\"windows\" /entry:\"mainCRTStartup\"" )
```